# Merging a couple of text files

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

Ok, so I need to do this with a couple of text files I have.
I need to merge the two files like this.

FILE 1 and FILE 2 need to become FILE 3.

FILE 1:

```
ABC:123
TUV:678
QRS:456
```

FILE 2:

```
123:XXX
678:EEE
456:DDD
```

FILE 3:

```
ABC:123:XXX
TUV:678:EEE
QRS:456:DDD
```

As you can see above, the second item is common in both FILE 1 and FILE 2. I just need to merge all items in FILE 1 and FILE 2 that have a common item like they are in FILE 3. I'd prefer to use grep, sed, cut, etc.

Comment: Do the files have blank lines. Also is the format constant?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file1
ABC:123
TUV:678
QRS:456
$ cat file2
123:XXX
678:EEE
456:DDD

awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}NR==FNR{f2[$2]=$0;next}$1 in f2{printf "%s:%s\n",f2[$1],$2}' file1 file2 >file3

$ cat file3
ABC:123:XXX
TUV:678:EEE
QRS:456:DDD
```

Comment: @thor : Newlines are indeed important. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU coreutils `sort` and `join`:

```
join -t: -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -t: -k2n file1) <(sort -t: -k1,1n file2)
```

Output:

```
123:ABC:XXX
456:QRS:DDD
678:TUV:EEE
```

#### Explanation

`join` needs to know which fields to join on and its input must be sorted. The options to `join` do the following:

- `-t:` use colon as the field separator
- `-1 2` use the second field in the first file as the key
- `-2 1` use the first field in the second file as the key

The `sort` invocations sort each file numerically by the key column.